# node.js Sequelize object JSON.stringify does not work on [Op.or]

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sequelize.js

I am using [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) in Node.js and I have where with SymbolOr [Op.or], and I want to create a unique key for each different where filter, and the same key for the same, but JSON.stringify does not work on symbols,
so :

```
const obj.where[Op.or]= { [Op.like]: `%\"mytext\":\"${param}\"%` }
```

So by doing JSON.stringify on `obj` is always empty. Can I get JSON.stringify to work on Symbols?

What I did: `JSON.stringify(replaceSymbolToString(filters))`

```
// ***************
// Items
// ***************
function isObject(o) {
return o instanceof Object && o.constructor === Object;
}
const operatorsMap = {
 [Op.and]: 'and',
 [Op.or]: 'or',
 [Op.gt]: 'gt',
 [Op.gte]: 'gte',
 [Op.lt]: 'lt',
 [Op.lte]: 'lte',
 [Op.ne]: 'ne',
 [Op.eq]: 'eq',
 [Op.not]: 'not',
 [Op.between]: 'between',
 [Op.notBetween]: 'notBetween',
 [Op.in]: 'in',
 [Op.notIn]: 'notIn',
 [Op.like]: 'like',
 [Op.notLike]: 'notLike',
 [Op.iLike]: 'ilike',
 [Op.notILike]: 'notILike',
 [Op.regexp]: 'regexp',
 [Op.notRegexp]: 'notRegexp',
 [Op.any]: 'any',
 };
//for JSON.Stringify to work when building cash key on Symbol which returns 
empty on it
function replaceSymbolToString(obj) {
 const newObj = {};

//Object.keys does not bring symbols keys

Reflect.ownKeys(obj).forEach((key) => {
const value= obj[key];
if (isObject(value)) {
  newObj[key] = replaceSymbolToString(value);
}else if (Array.isArray(value)){
  const arr = value.map(a=>{
   return replaceSymbolToString(a);
  });
  newObj[operatorsMap[key]?operatorsMap[key]:key] = arr;
}
else if (operatorsMap[key]) {
  newObj[operatorsMap[key]] = value;
} else {
  newObj[key] = value;
}
});
return newObj;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where JSON.stringify is involved in this. Are you using the result as a key to index your query options ?

Comment: (the implied suggestion is: why use JSON.stringify at all ? convenience ? clearly it's not convenient because of Symbols, so you might as well create your own hashing function)

Comment: yes i want to cash my results according to the user chosen where option